# Is Full Crawl needed when main characteristics of managed property are updated

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, managed-property, crawl

While editing any managed property from the Central administration's Search service application we can notice number of main characteristics of the property, such as `Searchable`, `Queryable`, `Retrievable` etc.

Now if I update any one of it, such as I am enabling `Searchable` to true and save the managed property changes, do I need a full crawl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

Please see [this TechNet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx#Plan_full_crawl) for when a full crawl is needed.

> A Search service application administrator or site collection administrator added or changed a managed property. A full crawl of all affected content sources is required for the new or changed managed property to take effect.